# SICP exercise 1.28 - miller-rabin primality test

Tags: performance, primes, lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node17.html)

> Exercise 1.28:
>
> One variant of the Fermat test that cannot be fooled is
>   called the Miller-Rabin test (Miller 1976; Rabin 1980). This starts
>   from an alternate form of Fermat’s Little Theorem, which states that
>   if \$n\$ is a prime number and \$a\$ is any positive integer less than \$n\$, then
>   \$a\$ raised to the \$n-1\$-st power is congruent to \$1 \mod n\$.
>
> To test the
>   primality of a number \$n\$ by the Miller-Rabin test, we pick a random
>   number \$a < n\$ and raise \$a\$ to the \$n-1\$-st power \$\mod n\$ using the expmod
>   procedure. However, whenever we perform the squaring step in expmod,
>   we check to see if we have discovered a “nontrivial square root of \$1
> \mod n\$,” that is, a number not equal to \$1\$ or \$n-1\$ whose square is
>   equal to \$1 \mod n\$.
>
> It is possible to prove that if such a nontrivial
>   square root of \$1\$ exists, then \$n\$ is not prime. It is also possible to
>   prove that if \$n\$ is an odd number that is not prime, then, for at least
>   half the numbers \$a < n\$, computing \$a^{n-1}\$ in this way will reveal a
>   nontrivial square root of \$1 \mod n\$. (This is why the Miller-Rabin
>   test cannot be fooled.)
>
> Modify the expmod procedure to signal if it
>   discovers a nontrivial square root of \$1\$, and use this to implement the
>   Miller-Rabin test with a procedure analogous to fermat-test. Check
>   your procedure by testing various known primes and non-primes.
>
> Hint:
>   One convenient way to make expmod signal is to have it return \$0\$.

According to the book this is a probabalistic algorithm. My tests gave mostly correct results.

Here's my code.

```
;; modified expmod procedure
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (if (and (not (= base 1)) 
                  (not (= base (- m 1))) 
                  (not (= exp (- m 1))) 
                  (= (remainder base m) 1))
             0
             (remainder 
              (expmod (square base) (/ exp 2) m)
              m)))
        (else
         (remainder 
          (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m))
          m))))

(define (miller-rabin-test n)
  (define (try-it a)
    (= (expmod a (- n 1) n) 1))
  (try-it (+ 1 (random (- n 1)))))

(define (fast-prime? n times)
  (cond ((= times 0) true)
        ((miller-rabin-test n) 
         (fast-prime? n (- times 1)))
        (else false)))
```

How can I improve this code and make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure I understood the SICP exercise correctly, I wrote my own version of the Miller-Rabin algorithm. You can look at [my code](https://gist.github.com/cky/ac11c20816b41f82c13bb59bb173cbad) and compare against yours.

With this in mind, here's my correctness-related feedback:

1. Your test expression, `(and (not (= base 1)) (not (= base (- m 1))) (not (= exp (- m 1))) (= (remainder base m) 1))`, seems to muddle up the relationship between the previous and current values. Really, what you want to find out is whether the previous value is between 2 and `(- m 2)` (mod m) and the current value is 1 (mod m).
2. Your `(remainder (expmod (square base) (/ exp 2) m) m)` is not optimal. All values returned by `expmod` should already be mod m so doing a further `remainder` call is pointless. You should, however, clamp the result of `square` to mod m.

Other style notes:

1. Not sure why you didn't just use a one-liner for the `miller-rabin-test` function:

   ```
   (define (miller-rabin-test n)
     (= (expmod (+ 1 (random (- n 1))) (- n 1) n) 1))
   ```

   or, if you're trying to break up the expression a bit,

   ```
   (define (miller-rabin-test n)
     (define a (+ 1 (random (- n 1))))
     (= (expmod a (- n 1) n) 1))
   ```

   No need for an internal function!
2. You can rewrite the main loop as a single `or`/`and` expression:

   ```
   (define (fast-prime? n times)
     (or (zero? times)
         (and (miller-rabin-test n)
              (fast-prime? n (- times 1)))))
   ```

Comment: I don't understand correctness-related feedback 2. You said I should "clamp the result of square to mod m". Can you explain what you mean by clamp? And you said "All values returned by expmod should already be mod m so doing a further remainder
call is pointless.", but isn't calling the remainder exactly why the return value is mod m?

Comment: @morbidCode Clamping x to mod m means `(modulo x m)`, so that the result is always between 0 and m-1. The return value of `expmod` should, by contract, _always_ be clamped to mod m, so the `remainder` call in your `(remainder (expmod (square base) (/ exp 2) m) m)` is redundant.

Comment: @morbidCode "You should, however, clamp the result of `square` to mod m" means use `(expmod (remainder (square base) m) (/ exp 2) m)` instead. Or, as in my version, `(remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) m)`. Notice how, in both cases, the shape of the expression is `(remainder (square ...))`, _not_ `(remainder (expmod ...))`.

Comment: I used (square base) in my solution so I can check base mod 1 inside the procedure. How does (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) m) gave the correct result? Note I haven't seen your code yet. I'll look at it when I've improved mine.

Comment: @morbidCode `(expmod base (/ exp 2) m)` is the recursive case. You then square the result to get what you need, then you mod m so you can compare the result to 1.

Comment: Ok, why is that better than my original approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40685/discussion-between-chris-jester-young-and-morbidcode).

Comment: Also, how would you check if base mod 1 if it's getting square outside of the procewdure and not being updated inside?

Comment: Hi @Chris Jester-Young, I've redone this exercise. I'm getting the feeling that I can solve this problem another way. It's not similar to yours and my old code because it generates an iterative process, but I think it still works and I think it fixed all problems you've encountered in my old code. Do you mind looking at it? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139221/sicp-exercise-1-28-miller-rabin-primality-test-part-ii Is this correct? Did I still follow the exercise? thanks!